# Failed to Switch User?

Tags: centos, sudo, su

On machine A and B (both running CentOS 7), I have:

```
# cat /etc/sudoers.d/custom
userA ALL=(userB:userB) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However, on machine A, when I run

```
[userA] $ sudo -ui userB
sudo: unknown user: i
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

when I run

```
[userA] $ sudo -iu userB
sudo: unknown user: env
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Tho, on machine B, both commands work fine.

`userA` and `userB` both exist on both machines.

Any idea?

Update 1 (based on @Bart's suggestion):

```
[userA]$ sudo -u -i userB
sudo: unknown user: -i
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
[userA]$ sudo -i -u userB
Need at least 3 arguments.
Run scl --help to get help.
[userA]$ sudo -u userB -i
Need at least 3 arguments.
Run scl --help to get help.

[userA]$ alias
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the paramenters, otherwise it will not work. So, do:

```bsh
sudo -i -u user
```

Comment: still doesn't work.  see my update above.

Comment: ok, that is weird. What if you tried sudo -u userB -i . and also, the sudoers entry seems a little off, try userA ALL=(userB) NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: also, check your system for aliases towards sudo (simple `alias` command will give you the output). not sure why SCL is involved here, presumably you have installed something from the repo that interfered with sudo..

Comment: updated my post.  I also tried to have `userA ALL=(userB) NOPASSWD:ALL` instead.  same outputs for all 3 commands.